# Which automata recognizes the language defined by the regular expression

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I am trying to understand why the following NFA is the one which recognizes the language defined by the regular expression:
$(00+10)0^*((1100+1110)0^*)^*$

[image]

As far as I can see the NFA will get stuck in $q_3$ with the first part of the regular expression $(00 + 10)$:
$q_0 \xrightarrow{0} q_1 \xrightarrow{01} q_3 \rightarrow {}$ stuck ? No $0$ to proceed to.

A clarification on why this NFA recognizes the regular expression is very much appreciated.

Comment: 00+10 means "00 or 10". If the word begins with 00, you end up in q2, and if the word begin with 10, you end up in q2 too (with 01 or 11, it is stuck in q1).

Comment: 00 or 10 brings the NFA to q2, not to q3.